# Maximise value of (X^Y)%M

Tags: algorithm, modulus

I know to calculate (X^Y)%M .Now my question is suppose we need to maximise (X^i)%M where i can vary between 0 to Y and M=10^9 + 7.What can i say about i.I mean when it will be maximum?

Input will consist of X and Y which can go upto 10^100 which i can handle by using BigIntegers of JAVA or using modular arithmetic in c++.

Comment: It will be maximum when the expression equals `M-1`. In fact, that expression can never go beyond `M-1`.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix By expression u mean X^I VALUE ?

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix means if it go beyond M-1 Then answer will always be M-1 ?

Comment: The modulus operation can never return a value equal or greater than its second operand, in your case, `M`. If `(X^Y)` goes beyond `M-1`, the maximum value will always be `M-1`

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix how can you be sure x^i%m ever equals (m-1), for any i?

Comment: What's fixed and what are you allowed to vary in this problem? You say you can "vary between 0 to Y", but you don't say **what** you can vary. I'm not at all clear about this from your question.

Comment: @pjs SEE i am given X and Y and i can vary the exponent of X upto Y

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix so is it sufficent to check if (x^y)%(M-1) is zero or not.If it is zero then answer should be M-1 otherwise (x^y)%M.Am i right?

Comment: @NiklasB. What u mean answer would always be M-1 except for X==0 and X==1.I think u got the question wrong For X=2 Y=2 answer is 4

Comment: @NiklasB. Mean if X%M ==0 || X%M ==1 Then answer is M-1 ?

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: The restriction on the exponent can be arbitrary, so you cannot generate all powers of `X`

Comment: @pjs: I think the exponent can vary between 0 and Y. So the task would be to find `max_{0 <= e <= Y} (X^e % (10^9 + 7))`

Comment: @pjs OK try X=5, M=11.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do, is to transfer

```
X=X%M
Y=Y%M
```

Notice, 10<sup>9</sup>+7 is much less than 10<sup>100</sup>. So, you won't need numbers larger than `long`. Long you will need, for the in-between results.

You should count the X<sup>i</sup> sequentally:

```
power[0]=X;
long i;
for(i=1; i<Y; i++){
    power[i]=(power[i-1]*X)%M;
    if (power[i] is in power[0..i-1]) {
       i--;
       break;
    }  
}
find max power[0..i];
```

Because they will be repeating often.

But I don't know if 10<sup>9</sup>+7 is prime or not. If it is, there will be no repeating until all numbers under 10<sup>9</sup>+7 will be reached. The only change will be that every X under 10<sup>9</sup>+7 will set its own unique recombination of numbers 1..10<sup>9</sup>+7.

In this case the max for every Y above 10<sup>9</sup>+7 will be 10<sup>9</sup>+7-1. As for smaller Y's you have to check sequentally, only without the check for the repetition.

Comment: `Y=Y%M` – shouldn't it be `Y=Y%(M-1)`?